# Prevent Javascript Injection

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I have a website that uses a captcha. 
http://blog.lukeblackamore.com/2009/10/sexy-captcha-new-drag-and-drop-captcha.html
But the problem is that it can be cracked easily using Javascript injection through:

```
var res=document.querySelector(".targetWrapper .target").style["background-    position"].match(/\d+/);
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".draggable"),function(a){
if(a.style["background-position"].match(/\d+/)[0]==res){
return document.querySelector(".captchaAnswer").value=a.id
}
});
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: This question is really rather silly. "I'm using a CAPTCHA that has known security issues. I'll post the code that exploits it. How can I prevent it?". Voting to close as "not a real question" - it's the equivalent of "I have a lock on my front door. I live at 123 4th Street in Sometown, Idaho in the US, and I keep a spare key under the front doormat. How do I stop someone from using it?"

Comment: Any javascript newbie can crack the code in seconds. So whether I post it here or not, there is no point in it. I just need a solution to the injection

Comment: The solution? Use a different CAPTCHA.

Comment: No. I dont think so. Most of them can be cracked with injection. Or else, use captcha services to bypass them. Nope. I'm looking to prevent the javascript injection. Does preventing the javascript in the address bar any solution ? Can that be even done ?

Comment: Then search here for `[javascript] prevent injection` and read one of the dozens of results.

Comment: captcha answers should be verified server-side only and then they are not vulnerable to client-side manipulation/injection.

Comment: Yes. The data is checked at server side. Yet the data is set at client side. So they can be manipulated easily

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to use a CAPTCHA without known security flaws.  I'd recommend Google's [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Comment: i believe I had read somewhere about the reCaptcha being broken some time. Actually I'm interested in this captcha, as it is a bit different from the normal ones that we deal with

Comment: Its not just this captcha alone..I want to prevent the Javascript injection to a limit

Comment: If just reCaptcha wasn't external...